# GItLab CI - Maven run test disabled tests with JUnit 5

Tags: java, maven, junit, gitlab, continuous-integration

I tried to run CI pipeline on GitLab, but all time maven goal "test" is failed. Maven runs disabled tests by @Disable annotation. This tests for not implemented yet functionality, and as expect is failed after run.

Pipline `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: >-
    -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
    -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository
    -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: >-
    --batch-mode
    --no-transfer-progress
    --fail-at-end

image: maven:3-openjdk-17

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

Test job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test'
  allow_failure: true
```

Dependensies in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.4</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
      ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2</version>
    </plugin>
    ...
  <plugins>
<build>
```

Everything works for local `mvn test`

I tried to remove `--fail-at-end for` `MAVEN_CLI_OPTS` but nothing to change.

Comment: You have to add junit-jupiter-engine as a dependency also using spring-boot-dependencies instead of spring-boot-starter-parent...

Answer (score 0):

Just need to replace the image tag in pipeline setup.

**Before:** `image: maven:3-openjdk-17`

**After:** `image: maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17`

Comment: What is the reason that this works? Is there an incompatibility with Maven 3.9.x?